# HTML body onload() property

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote the following functions:

```
function fill(value) {
    return (value > 9) ? "" + value : "0" + value;
}

function fillMili(value) {
    value %= 1000;
    return (value <= 9) ? "00" + value : 
           (value <= 99) ? "0" + value :
           "" + value;  
};

function showClock() {
    var now = new Date;

    time = fill(now.getHours()) + " : " + fill(now.getMinutes()) + " : " + fill(now.getSeconds()) + " : " + fill(now.getMilliseconds());

    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = time;

    setTimeout("showClock()",1);
}
```

And then put the function into the body tag and create a div tag:

```
<body onload="showClock()">
    <div id="clock">
    </div>
```

The page will show a fine clock. But if I change this line of code

```
setTimeout("showClock()",1);
```

to

```
setInterval("showClock()",1);
```

The browser will freeze on loading this page.

I know that the function `setTimeout()` will execute the assigned function once and the function `setInterval()` will execute the assigned function several times.

I have 2 questions: how does the `onload` property of the `body` work and why doesn't the function `setInterval()` work in this code?

UPDATE: I want to show a clock displaying milliseconds. Does the `onload` property repeat the function?

Comment: You're running the showClock function with `setInterval` every 1 milisecond. That's very quick....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the syntax of setInterval:

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(func, delay[, param1, param2, ...]);
```

With delay in miliseconds. Besides that there is an ancient limit on this delay:

> Minimum/ maximum delay and timeout nesting
>
> Historically browsers implement setTimeout() "clamping": successive
> setTimeout() calls with delay smaller than the "minimum delay" limit
> are forced to use at least the minimum delay. The minimum delay,
> DOM_MIN_TIMEOUT_VALUE, is 4 ms (stored in a preference in Firefox:
> dom.min_timeout_value), with a DOM_CLAMP_TIMEOUT_NESTING_LEVEL of 5ms.
>
> In fact, 4ms is specified by the HTML5 spec and is consistent across
> browsers released in 2010 and onward. Prior to (Firefox 5.0 /
> Thunderbird 5.0 / SeaMonkey 2.2), the minimum timeout value for nested
> timeouts was 10 ms.

Source: [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting)

Besides the fact of the above mentioned minimum delay, you should ask yourself the question why you're running a clock-function every milisecond. You'd beter do it every 1000ms = 1 second.

If you want to show the miliseconds you should find an other way for the display as the minimum delay is still in force.

Comment: I know that but the `setTimeout()` works fine with the clock but `setInterval()` won't. And yes, I want to show the milliseconds.

Comment: Well actually your settimeout function does not work fine. Because it only runs once you won't notice the difference of 1ms or 4/10ms the minimum.

Comment: I use `setTimeout()` and the clock runs continuously. Does the `onload` property repeat the function?

Answer (score 1):

The time parameter in setInterval(....) function is in miliseconds. 1 milisecond is very fast for executing function, and that is probably why the page freezes. Try setting it to 1000 (1000 ms = 1 second).

See here for more: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: I 'intended' to use 1 millisecond interval, because I want to show a clock with millisecond display.

Comment: This is way too fast for a browser. I think there is a relative post posted. But why would you like such a fast reloading? Please review your program's logic, there might be a better way to do it.

Comment: If I use `setInterval()`, I won't need to put it into the `start()` function and put that `setInterval()` into the body :P So I want to know about the `onload` property

Comment: Onload is called when the document has finished loading.
See here for more: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 1):

The browser should not freeze. Get rid of the `onload` in the `<body>` tag and have this in the page `<head>` section:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var clock = document.getElementById("clock");
    window.setInterval(showClock, 1);
    showClock();
    function showClock() {
        var now = new Date();
        var time = fill(now.getHours()) + " : " + fill(now.getMinutes()) + " : " + fill(now.getSeconds()) + " : " + fill(now.getMilliseconds());
        clock.innerHTML = time;
    }
}
```

This should make it bit faster and more elegant.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/CeAah/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should realize that what you're trying to do is impossible, given the current browser implementation and hardware.

On my computer the time it takes for Chrome to repaint a 3x16 area on the screen is about 300 ms. To have 1000 such updates it would take 5 minutes. You want to do it one second. You are clearly asking too much from your hardware.

If you really need that much performance (as if...) inside a webbrowser, you should write a native plugin, still I doubt you will be able to redraw a part of your screen that many times a second (at least you would need a 1000hz monitor, which would be silly to produce).

Rethink your application logic: even if you show a millisecond clock, the human eye can't see anything that changes faster than 72 times in a second, so you could as well update your clock a more reasonable ~25 times a second and no one would be able to see the difference. It would still be a website I wouldn't want use, because it would slow down my browser, but at least it will not freeze.

Using a number which doesn't have 2 and 5 factors will ensure that last digit shown won't repeat too often

```
setInterval("showClock()", 37);
```

Edit:

There's a bigger issue in your code, as pointed out by Shadow Wizard, that is you are calling setInterval *every time you update your clock*, which sets up a lot of timers, as fast as possible. You should be calling that function only once, for example in the onload event:

```
<body onload="startClock()">
```

and then add the `startClock` function:

```
function startClock() { setInterval("showClock()", 1); }
```

and remove the `setInterval` call from `showClock`:

```
function showClock() {
    var now = new Date;

    time = fill(now.getHours()) + " : " + fill(now.getMinutes()) + " : " + fill(now.getSeconds()) + " : " + fill(now.getMilliseconds());

    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = time;

    // remove! //setTimeout("showClock()",1);
}
```

I am still suggesting that you should not need to update your page that often, but that's your call.